# Filter based on other observable's recent past messages

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

I'm trying to filter messages out of an observable based on the messages of another observable.

```
navCmds          --A----B---C--A------D-----------------C-----D----E--->

navNotifications ----A----X---B-C-A---D------------------------DCA---E->

result           ---------X--------------------------------------A----->
```

In my program I send navigation commands to an external application.
The application notifies me of what screens it changed to.
Notifications can be because I sent a navigation command, but also because a user navigated in the application itself.
I want to get a stream with only the navigated commands that are not a result of messages I sent.

Because the other application is not in my control, I cannot extend the messages with a correlation id or other new field.

The way I thought to tackle this

- create windows on the navCmds
- filter the navNotifications on the latest window

Notifications that are not a direct response for a commmand, but WERE sent as cmd earlier in the window will be lost.
This is an acceptable compromise.

```
const notificationsStopped$ = this.navCmds$.pipe(debounceTime(500));
const cmdWindows$ = this.navCmds$.pipe(windowOperator(notificationsStopped$));

const result$ = this.navNotifications$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(cmdWindows$),
    filter(([notification, pastCmds$]) => // How to filter here?)
);
```

Is there an easier way?
How do I do the filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter `navNotifications` by `navCmds` - we want to gather all `navCmds` with `scan`.

> scan - Reduce over time.

We assume that `pastCmd` is serializable to put it in object. Also `Map` can be used as it can use reference as a key

```
const allPastCmds$ = pastCmds$.pipe(scan(acc, cur)=>({...acc, [cur]: true}),{});
```

`notificationExist` check if `notification` in `allPastCmds`

```
filter(([notification, allPastCmds]) => !notificationExist(notification, allPastCmds)
```

Comment: I'm going to test this today, but it looks like a good solution

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood right your problem, I would make a slight change to the **marble diagrams** you have proposed for your problem.

In particular, I would change the last `DCA` sequence of `navNotifications` to `CDA`, to reflect the fact that in the `navCmds` sequence, first you send `C` and then `D`. This means that the **marble diagrams** would look like this

```
navCmds          --A----B---C--A------D-----------------C-----D----E--->

navNotifications ----A----X---B-C-A---D------------------------CDA---E->

result           ---------X--------------------------------------A----->
```

Assuming this is right, which has to be confirmed, you could consider a solution along these lines

```
const queue = new Array<any>();

navCmds$.pipe(
  tap(cmd => queue.push(cmd)),
  switchMap(() => {
    return navNotifications$.pipe(
      switchMap(notification => {
        const cmdFromQueue = queue[0];
        if (notification === cmdFromQueue) {
          queue.shift();
          return empty();
        } else {
          return of(notification);
        }
      })
    )
  })
)
```

The idea here is

- first to create a `queue` where you store the commands sent
- any time a new command is emitted by `navCmds$`, the value is pushed
  in the `queue` and the stream is switched to `navNotifications$`
  which checks the `queue` and emits the `notification` if it is
  different from the last command processed

This solution requires **state** to be maintained via the `queue` variable, but this can be hidden using custom pipeable operators.

These solutions have been tested with the following test data

```
const navCmds$ = new Subject<any>();
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('A')}, 30);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('B')}, 80);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('C')}, 120);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('A')}, 150);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('D')}, 220);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('C1')}, 320);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('D1')}, 380);
setTimeout(() => {navCmds$.next('E')}, 430);


const navNotifications$ = new Subject<any>();
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('A')}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('X1')}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('X2')}, 110);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('B')}, 130);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('Y1')}, 140);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('Y2')}, 150);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('C')}, 160);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('A')}, 180);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('D')}, 230); // slightly delayed
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('C1')}, 390); // inverted
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('D1')}, 400); // inverted
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('A1')}, 410);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('A2')}, 420);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('A3')}, 440);
setTimeout(() => {navNotifications$.next('E')}, 460);
```

Comment: If I could take that assumption I think this would indeed be a good solution, but I'm afraid we can't be certain about the order of the responses.

Comment: Maybe the "order of the responses" problem can be addressed by treating `queue` as an array rather than as a real queue. Which means using `indexOf` rather than going directly to the first element of `queue` and using `splice` rather than `shift`.

Comment: yeah, maybe that can work. It would do away with the idea of the window. Maybe a simpler solution than what I was aiming at. Will have to test it.